# Remove residual variance paths of y-indicators in sempaths (package: semplot)

Tags: r, r-lavaan, semplot

I am using the following code semPlot::semPaths to plot a lavaan model:

```
semPaths(object = fit,
         what = "stand",
         nCharNodes = 0,
         layout = "tree",
         fade = FALSE,
         exoCov = FALSE,
         residuals = FALSE,
         intercepts = FALSE,
         rotation = 2,
         sizeMan = 5,
         sizeLat = 10,
         edge.label.cex = 1.5,
         minimum=0.16,
         allVars = FALSE,
         equalizeManifests = FALSE,
         fixedStyle = 2)
```

And this is the figure from the semPaths output:

[image]

I want to remove all the red paths on the y-indicators (i.e., red lines on the right-hand side of the model). What argument can I add to remove them? Thanks.

I have tried adding various arguments to the semPaths() code based on R documentation and previous stackoverflow queries. These additional arguments are removing different paths and numbers, except for the paths I want to remove. Most arguments are included in the current code.